# Pagination count returning no value

Tags: php, mysqli

Was hoping someone could give me some help.  I have been trying to learn pagination but have run into an issue.  when I run this to get my total rows count:

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM item WHERE fid='17'";
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
 $rows = $row[0];
```

$rows comes back with no value, I am under the impression that $rows should contain the total number of records from item with the fid of 17, when I run  `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM item WHERE fid='17'` in phpmyadmin it returns 98 which is the correct count.  Directly before the above code I use this code to connect to the db, which I use again later to display the records which works fine.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$dbname");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

This statement displays records later in the script

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE fid='17' ORDER BY id DESC $limit ");
```

So there is data and the info is correct.

I have been following this tutorial on the subject http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1349  and it works like a charm on his example in the video, all I have changed is the database particulars to mine.  Can't figure this one out, been stuck for days so now I am bothering you fine folks.

Update:  Changed

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
 $rows = $row[0];
```

to

```
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
// Return the number of rows in result set
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

And everything is working now.  Still wish I knew what was wrong with my original code but I will be moving on.  Thanks Phil Perry for all your help this morning!

Comment: What happens if you change `(*)` to just `*`? Since $con works later on, I'll assume that you have it correctly connected at this point.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I tried that earlier and no difference was noticed.

Comment: Then, have you confirmed that you have a good connection (`$con`) at this point?

Comment: Yea, the connection is good.  directly before that I have   $con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$dbname");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }    and I use $con later without issue.

Comment: Is there another way you could suggest to get the total count of rows?  I feel like the problem may lie with mysqli_fetch_row.   This is the first time I have ever used COUNT so not sure of other ways

Comment: Well, you _could_ `SELECT * FROM...` and then call `mysqli_num_rows($query)`. Probably slower than `SELECT count(*)`. BTW, I presume that **item** is not a reserved word in SQL. You can always wrap table and field names in backticks (not quotes ' or "). You could also try `SELECT count(*) AS myCount...`.

Comment: Thanks Phil, mysqli_num_rows worked!  Everything is good now though I still wish I could figure out why my original code didn't work I'm gonna just go with the working code you helped me with.  If you want to submit your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks again I really appreciate your help!  Been stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could `SELECT * FROM...` and then call `mysqli_num_rows($query)`. Probably slower than `SELECT count(*)`. BTW, I presume that item is not a reserved word in SQL. You can always wrap table and field names in backticks (not quotes ' or "). You could also try `SELECT count(*) AS myCount...`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE fid='17'";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$rows = $row[0];
```

Comment: make connection separate,

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database");

Comment: I have the connection separate currently  though I am using mysqli     // Create connection

$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$dbname");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }                $con works later to display records without issue.   If i remove $con from $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) there is no way it would work.  Not sure what I would be testing with that

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you changed row to array, I will give that a shot.  edit: there was no change, $rows still has no value